# PHP issue with classes

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class, adodb

I am having a little problem with the following code:

```
<?php
class appointments
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    function usercompany($uid)
    {
        return $this->conn->getone("SELECT company FROM signup WHERE UID = '".$uid."'");
    }

    function hastemplate($uid)
    {
        return $this->conn->getone("SELECT COUNT(parentid) FROM appointments_templates WHERE parentid = '$uid'");
    }

    function gettemplate($uid)
    {
        if($this->hastemplate($uid)){
            return $this->conn->getrow("SELECT * FROM appointments_templates WHERE parentid = '" . $uid . "'");
        } else {
            $appointment_template = 'This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at '. $this->usercompany($uid);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO appointments_templates SET parentid = '" . $uid . "', content = '" . $appointment_template . "'";
            $this->conn->execute($sql);

            return $this->gettemplate($uid);
        }
    }  
}
?>
```

When I call `usercompany($uid)` by itself I get a correct result which is the users company. However when I call `gettemplate($uid)` the new template gets added to the database but without the results of `usercompany($uid)`. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** Regarding the INSERT syntax: http://milov.nl/2836

To recap: **Issue is not that its not getting added to the database** but rather than getting inserted as "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at XYZ Inc." its getting added as "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at "

Comment: can you put the code that uses this class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be you have **wrong syntax** for **insert** query. You can refer the syntax for mysql insert query here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Try using this instead using single quotes,

$appointment_template = "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at ". $this->usercompany($uid)."";

Comment: The issue is not that its not getting added to the database but rather the issue is its getting added as "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at" instead of "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at XYZ Inc."

Comment: Also $appointment_template = "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at ". $this->usercompany($uid).""; doesnt work.

Comment: try storing $this->usercompany($uid) in a variable and see whether the function returns any value. i mean inside the gettemplate .

Comment: @MeisamMulla What is the return value of $this->usercompany($uid) ? Probably it is returning an empty string...

Comment: It is the users company name. When I call $appointment->usercompany($uid) I get the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

`insert` statements do not work like that. Rather than:

```sql
insert into table set column1 = value1, column2 = value2
```

They work like this:

```sql
insert into table (column1, column2) values (value1, value2)
```

Additionally, I don't see any escaping going on, so I hope nobody has a company with an apostrophe in its name.

Comment: The issue is not that its not getting added to the database but rather the issue is its getting added as "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at" instead of "This is a reminder to let you know that you have an appointment on {appointment} at XYZ Inc." The company name is escaped when its stored in the database.